# Moving a JSON array which have another array elements to the same LEVEL

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON which have an element ***array_within_array*** in another array. So I want to pull both ***array_within_array*** element and upper array element(***event_array***) to root level using **jq**.
So here there are 3 events.

1. meal_selection
2. login
3. placed_order

Event ***placed_order*** have two sub-events in array. So after conversion there should be 4 events(1 from ***meal_selection***, 1 from ***login*** and 2 from ***placed_order***). these all should be on the same level.
Here is the JSON

```
{
    "region": "USA",
    "user_id": "123",
    "event_array": [{
            "event_attributes": {
                "date": "2021-08-17",
                "category": "lunch",
                "location": "office"
            },
            "event_name": "meal_selection",
            "created_at": "2021-08-13 01:28:57"
        },
        {
            "event_name": "login",
            "created_at": "2021-08-13 01:29:02"
        },
        {
            "event_attributes": {
                "array_within_array": [
                    {
                "date": "2021-08-17",
                "category": "lunch",
                "location": "office"
                    },
                    {
                "date": "2021-08-18",
                "category": "dinner",
                "location": "home"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "event_name": "placed_order",
            "created_at": "2021-08-13 01:28:08"
        }
        ]
}
```

and I want to convert to the below one

```
{
  "region": "USA",
  "user_id": "123",
  "event_attributes": {
    "date": "2021-08-17",
    "category": "lunch",
    "location": "office"
  },
  "event_name": "meal_selection",
  "created_at": "2021-08-13 01:28:57"
}
{
  "region": "USA",
  "user_id": "123",
  "event_name": "login",
  "created_at": "2021-08-13 01:29:02"
}
{
  "region": "USA",
  "user_id": "123",
  "event_attributes": {
    "date": "2021-08-17",
    "category": "lunch",
    "location": "office"
  },
  "event_name": "placed_order",
  "created_at": "2021-08-13 01:28:08"
}
{
  "region": "USA",
  "user_id": "123",
  "event_attributes": {
    "date": "2021-08-18",
    "category": "dinner",
    "location": "home"
  },
  "event_name": "placed_order",
  "created_at": "2021-08-13 01:28:08"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward solution that keeps things simple by using two steps:

```
{ region, user_id} + (.event_array[] )
| if .event_attributes|has("array_within_array")
  then .event_attributes.array_within_array as $a
  | .event_attributes = $a[]
  else .
  end
```